# Pydantic field does not take value

Tags: python, pydantic

While attempting to name a Pydantic field `schema`, I received the following error:

```
NameError: Field name "schema" shadows a BaseModel attribute; use a different field name with "alias='schema'".
```

Following [the documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#reserved-names), I attempted to use an alias to avoid the clash. See code below:

```
from pydantic import StrictStr, Field
from pydantic.main import BaseModel    

class CreateStreamPayload(BaseModel):
          name: StrictStr
          _schema: dict[str: str] = Field(alias='schema')
```

Upon trying to instantiate CreateStreamPayload in the following way:

```
a = CreateStreamPayload(name= "joe",
            _schema= {"name": "a name"})
```

The resulting instance has only a value for `name`, nothing else.

```
a.dict()
{'name': 'joe'}
```

This makes absolutely no sense to me, can someone please explain what is happening?

Many thanks

Comment: Leading underscores represent private fields in Python.  I suggest appending it: `schema_: ...`

Comment: Thanks @MaximilianBurszley, it seems to have worked. If you would like to answer the question, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#automatically-excluded-attributes):

> Class variables which begin with an underscore and attributes annotated with `typing.ClassVar` will be automatically excluded from the model.

In general, *append* an underscore to avoid conflicts as leading underscores are seen as either dunder (magic) members or private members: `_schema` ➡ `schema_`